# How do I overcome this PNG rendering problem of a SVG?

Tags: inkscape, svg

I uploaded a human body diagram showing the signs and symptoms of Hodgkin's lymphoma (http://health-and-medicine.wikia.com/wiki/File:Symptoms_of_Hodgkin_lymphoma.svg) to my Wiki but for some reason in the PNG versions of this SVG there are black spots that aren't there in the original SVG, does anyone have any ideas of how I could overcome this problem? When I convert my SVG to PNG in Inkscape no such problem occurs.

Comment: Very strange. Are the png images generated by mediawiki? Could your problem be related with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351403/invalid-svg-to-png-conversion-via-rsvg-in-mediawiki)?

Comment: Sure are created by MediaWiki. I don't understand enough about it though to know if it is via the package `librsvg`.

Comment: I'm sorry I have no other ideas for now. An export with Inkscape works well. Have you tried to post a message to [Wikia support](http://www.wikia.com/Special:Contact)?

Comment: FYI the black areas also appear in my Xubuntu desktop thumbnails for your svg.  I see them in my own work sometimes for text blocks and clipped objects (of which you have many).
Converting the text to paths usually sorts the preview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outline your text // Convert your text to paths

Edit: I was too fast, I've had this problem before with inkscape but converting texts to paths fixed the problem for me